# Can't modify files in my shared folder (virtualbox, guest is Ubuntu, host is windows 7)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, file-sharing

I'm using virtual-box. The guest is Ubuntu. The host is Windows 7. I have a shared folder (shared by the host and the guest).

The problem is that in the guest (Ubuntu) I cannot `rename/delete/edit` the files in the shared folder. For instance, after I edit the file and try to save it I get the following error message:

> Could not save the file fileName. Unexpected error: Error renaming temporary file: text file busy

In the host (Windows) I can rename/edit/delete without any problem. What can I do?

Answer (score 8):

You may suffer from [bug #34813](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/34813), where access to shares on Windows systems is broken. Access to files on Ubuntu hosts is not affected.

### Troubleshoot Shared Folders in Virtual Box

To investigate if your shared folders are setup correctly you may go through the following steps:

- Install the latest release of [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
- Make sure Guest Additions meet your VBox release.
- Not define shared folders as read-only if you need write access.
- Guest users need to be in the group `vboxsf` for auto-mounted shares.
- Mount temporary shares with option rw and appropriate uid for write access,

  (e.g. `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000 sharename mountpoint`)

Answer (score 2):

How did you mount that shared folder?

I had the same problem but with power of fstab I finally manage to freely access my shared folder - just have added the line:

```
//shareIP/sharedFolder mountpoint smbfs rw,umask=777,uid=linuxUID,username=winUsername,password=winPassword,auto 0 0
```

Now you can reboot your OS or just do `sudo mount <mountpoint>`.

Somehow with "native" vbox sharing I could not achieve this - not even access shared folder although it was visible.